# Getting IllegalArgumentException in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I executed the below script

```
  Actions a1 = new Actions(driver);
  a1.moveToElement(Dropdown).click().keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).keyDown(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).keyDown(Keys.ENTER);
```

but I am getting the below exception :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Key Down / Up events only make
sense for modifier keys.
How do I solve this ??

Comment: which browser and whic chrome driver version are you using

Comment: chrome and ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96

Answer (score 0):

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/keyboard/

KeyDown and KeyUp are supported only for modifier keys which are ctrl,alt and shift

try using Key.chords with send keys

https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html

```
element.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT+"a"))
```